# How to set TYPO3_CONTEXT in ddev

Tags: typo3, ddev

My ddev environment always runs in production mode. How to change that?

`SetEnv TYPO3_CONTEXT Development`

Comment: How is your PHP set up? mod_php (apache), CGI, PHP fpm?

Comment: The Question is ddev specific > https://github.com/drud/ddev

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit 2023-04-25: There are now many ways to set environment variables that don't require any of this. You can use a `.ddev/.env`, or add an environment variable to `web_environment`, etc. See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/customization-extendibility/#providing-custom-environment-variables-to-a-container

The [answer by @marcel is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67901820/215713) these days.

Original answer:

There's an easier way that doesn't involve such complexity.

Create a .ddev/docker-compose.typo3.yaml with these contents:

```yaml
    services:
      web:
        environment:
          - TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development
```

This does *nothing* beyond adding that environment variable in the web container. Note that the name of the docker-compose file is not important, it could be `docker-compose.envstuff.yaml`

Comment: Despite my optimism, this didn't work in ddev v0.18.0, but does work in v0.19.0

Comment: is the `version: '3.6'` important? what does this version relate to?

Comment: `version: 3.6` is obsolete for some time now. It's ignored, but not necessary.

Comment: Also, I updated because this was hopelessly out of date

Comment: so it's related to the ddev version?

Comment: No, docker-compose used to have a `version` tag like this. It no longer does. But regardless, you don't need to be doing this. See the other answer or this updated answer.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification and your patience with me ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Just for those who stumble upon this question here.
In newer versions of ddev (I have v1.17.5), you have to edit the file `.ddev/config.yml` with nano o.e.
You can just replace the line

```
web_environment: []
```

by

```
web_environment:
 - TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development
```

Afterwards you have to restart the environment via `ddev restart`

Answer (score 2):

you have to setup an individual nginx configuration.
To do so:

1. start up ddev
2. ssh into machine with ddev ssh
3. copy the contents of typo3 config within /etc/nginx/nginx-site-typo3.conf
4. create nginx-site.conf file within the .ddev directory of your project
5. copy the standard configuration in that file
6. Look for "location ~ .php$ { .... }" within the newly created config file
7. Add the line fastcgi_param TYPO3_CONTEXT YOURCONTEXT;
8. save the file
9. do ddev restart

that's it

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the official ddev documentation page for this topic:

https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/cms-settings/#setup-a-base-variant-since-typo3-95

I applied this in a local TYPO3 v12 project and it worked perfectly. So go to your **.ddev** folder and change the value for **web_environment**, like so:

```
web_environment:
- TYPO3_CONTEXT=Development/DDEV
```

After this change you need to restart your project:

```
ddev restart
```